# Copy values respectively from left to right in Apex Oracle

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X9sN.png)I have left series of data items P1_A , P1_B, P1_C and I want to copy them to right series respectively P1_A1, P1_B1 and P1_C1 they are in the same tab . I have created a button and dynamic action to do that, I've choosen set value for the button and P1_A1,P1_B1,P1_C1 in affected items. Remains JS to clone values. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "left and right series" mean, but - to me - it looks as a matter of a

- button, which submits the page
- process, which fires when button is pressed and does this:

  ```
  :P1_A1 := :P1_A;
  :P1_B1 := :P1_B;
  :P1_C1 := :P1_C;
  ```

In other words, you don't need dynamic action nor JavaScript to do that.

Comment: I've added image for what I want.